# After upgrade magento 2.1.11 => 2.2.3, I got below error how to fixed it

Tags: css, frontend, upgrade, header, version

`Notice: Undefined index: src in /vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Generator/Head.php` on line 125

How to fix it. please reply.

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable developer mode before upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Put your store in developer mode `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` and make sure you have cleared the following directories:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/generation/*
```

It could be a third-party extension issue too.

Comment: Indeed, and a technical brainstorming can be found https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11224